# Programmable current laser drive circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, constant-current, laser

I'm trying to design a circuit to programmably control the laser drive current from 0-200mA. The current needs to stable (<50uA variation)  but with a settling time of <1us (faster if possible). The circuit has a current limiting resistor and an on/off switch. There is also a monitor ADC to measure the current.

I'm concerned about:

- Oscillation between `OA1` and `M1`
- DAC output variation due to supply ect.

Should a cap and resistor be placed in the feedback loop or on the `OA1` output to limit possible oscillations?

What are the calculation steps to work out the required slew rate / bandwidth of the op-amp and filter value?

Is there a way to improve the DAC output? [This circuit](http://electronicdesign.com/analog/simple-circuit-drives-manages-laser-diodes-output) uses a ratiometric DAC, is this a good option?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqABaj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: The application requires the lasers be completely off at all times when `LASER_ON` is low.

Comment: On/off switch may be better implemented using an opamp with a shutdown input and a pulldown for M1's gate. Laser diodes are very sensitive to current excursions and to switch it using M2 may result in instability or overshoot by OA1/M1 when turned on. You will probably need either a gate resistor or an isolating (bipolar) transistor, or both, to avoid problems of a capacitive load for OA1. In fact, replacing M1 with a BJT may make things easier on both counts.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yes, using an op-amp with shutdown sounds like a better solution to ensuring the laser is off.

Comment: Opamps with the shutdown function normally make the output high impedance when it's enabled. This would work particularly well if M1 became a BJT. You'll probably still want a base resistor to help linearize the load characteristic and make it more controllable. Main problem with high current opamps is that they tend to be either slow or expensive, but you can get decently fast power transistors.

Comment: Normally mosfets have a 10 ohm to 22 ohm resistor of 1/8 to 1/4 watt connected directly at the gate in series with its drive signal. You will see this in all good designs and all SMPS designs. It helps remove ringing at the drain pin, and stop self-oscillation.

Answer (score 1):

For high speed settling, I'd dump M1 altogether if possible and use a high current opamp to feed the laser directly, that way you avoid the problems that come from driving the capacitive gate (using a fast BJT instead would also probably work as fixed base current means fixed collector current. M2 would interfere with the current measurement a little as it has some resistance. Using a pull down on the dac instead (or a DAC with an output disable function) means you can use really small high speed transistors. While using the opamp to drive the laser directly ensures a real fast stable response as there is the bare minimum of unwanted parasitics. (make R2 a kOhm or more and make M1 a really low output capacitance part otherwise you'll get a low pass filter)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQpMvB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

).

Comment: This seems like a great idea in terms of speed. Are there any factors of stability you can think of if I used a really fast op-amp?

I like @OleksandrR.'s suggestion of using an op-amp with shutdown with this.

Comment: If you've got a unity gain stable opamp, the only thing I can think of off the top of my head is the bandwidth which will only limit how fast you can change the current, but an opamp with an output disable would be really good, it's basically have the same effect, I just liked the pull down transistor because it's the same as commanding the DAC to go to 0mA, so you shouldn't have any overshoot problems when you turn it back on. High current opamps don't have bandwidths so high that I'd expect them to do too many strange things, a few 10s of MHz is probably all you'll get.